# Maplex ignores leading characters like ,,

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, maplex

I try to label some geologic features with Maplex. A given condition for naming is that some geological units start with a double comma ,, . So the label should look like ,,ta or ,,ya . Whenever I try to label, Maplex is not showing the leading characters. Using the standard label engine works and shows the right result, but causes more problems in conflict detection. Any ideas how to convince Maplex to give me the ,, ?

In Germany a , usually is used as decimal sign in numbers, not as separator. So my PC is set to use , as decimal sign.

Comment: You can use quotes to do this like "<BSE>" &",," &[Name]

Comment: Thank you Mapperz. Unfortunately it's not working. My variable [LABEL] contains a string ,,ta and many others, some with leading,, some without. so its a bad idea to put ,, fixed at the beginning. Anyways Maplex is not able to show me the string with its leading ,,. Even if i put a string like ",,"&[LABEL] Maplex cannot show me the ,,. If I use the regular labeling method it shows the string in its right way, but in very bad placement.

Comment: Fixed! Maplex takes , as stacking separator. Disabled stacking and , appears.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to disable stacking altogether - it is possible to delete individual stacking characters by following the instructions on the [Adding and removing stacking characters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/map/working-with-text/stacking-labels-add-and-remove-stacking-characters.htm) of the ArcGIS Desktop Help.

Comment: You are absolutely right, its also possible to delete individual characters. Thanks for the complement!